# From liquid to solid by beating

Tags: everyday-chemistry, bond

I understand how liquids can become solids by decreasing temperature. To my understanding this is because the molecules slow down and are able to form bonds.

However, I'm having problems understanding how we can create a solid out of liquid by beating it, such as the case with cream becoming butter if you beat it long enough.

What is going on in such a process?

Answer (score 4):

Butter is at least 80% milk fat, 16% water and about 3% milk solids (such as proteins and sugars). The milk fat is normally a solid at room temperature. To make butter, cream is separated from the milk and pasteurized. The cream is then churned (beaten) to separate out buttermilk (mostly water) from the milk fat (butter). So, when butter is made, a solid is separated from a solution (actually an emulsion).

The closest thing I can think of where a liquid is transformed into a solid is beaten egg whites. In this case, air is mixed into the liquid to form an emulsion. It appears solid (but is still a liquid) since the liquid surrounds many air bubbles (which don't pop since they are very small). When you cook the beaten egg whites, then the protein in the egg white are denatured and become a solid.

Answer (score 2):

There's also Non-Newtonian Shear Thickening Fluids.  However I cannot personally explain how beating them turns them solid (temporarily).  But as best I understand, nobody is 100% sure so I'm not too embarrassed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_thickening

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid

However LDC3s explaination of butter is likely a more accurate answer to your question, and its not actually a change of state from liquid to solid as a result of impact force, but rather water being removed from a material that is its own solid.

Think of taking the water out of salt water.

Comment: Indeed, shear thickening fluids turn solid (or rather, behave like a solid) when force is applied. However, this is indeed only temporarily, therefore it cannot explain how butter *permanently* solidifies by beating.

Comment: By the way, if you are interested in understanding more about shear thickening. There is an excellent review paper here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0269.pdf